# First Price Auctions

Tags: auction-theory

[image]

[image]

Please tell me where I am wrong? I am asking this because sub-question a) didn't went as expected. I hope I did the derivates well for b) Furthermore, should I add more reasoning at c)? 
My answers are:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You haven’t written down the cdf $G$ correctly. Also, $s_i^*$ is *not* a dominant strategy.

Comment: Should it be x/2 + 1?

Comment: No, it shouldn’t. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)